# XOR mathematical function with output 0 or 1

Tags: logic

Good day
I want to find a function that XOR two binary numbers together so that the result is either zero or one.
for example I want to XOR 1001 and 0010 and take 1(because they are not same!)
but I want a mathematical function not an algorithm.

thanks all.

Comment: if you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take the difference.

If $a-b=0,$ the result is $1.$
Otherwise it is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

$|a-b|$ should work

$|1-1|=|0|=0$

$|1-0|=|1|=1$

$|0-1|=|-1|=1$

$|0-0|=|0|=0$